# help with posing or rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging

I downloaded a [meeseeks model from cgtrader](https://www.cgtrader.com/items/2985393/download-page). I am so confused how to model the figure to any pose I want. There are these gray triangles which I believe are bones and then there are all these color circles and lines that I've never seen before, so I don't know what they are called. But when I just try to rotate the arm the bone and line will rotate but the actual meeseeks arm doesn't do anything. I'm just trying to get him to hold his hands out in front of him to hold a Rubik cube. Does anyone know how I can pose the guy?

[image]
[image]

Comment: that rig appears to have a switch built-in to switch between the fk and ik bones. You'll have to looks for that switch if you want to pose him in fk

Comment: What is fk and ik bones

Comment: fk = forward kinematics, ik = inverse kinematics. They're two types of bone that function differently. The one you are posing in the image is an fk bone

Comment: I would recommend to watch some beginner rigging tutorials before using a complicated rig...might be more helpful then being frustrated with a complicated rig...And i also felt helpless with rigs in my beginning.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations being as though you may be more experienced than i. so i figured maybe you might have found which were well explained for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Have a look here [Blender 2.8/2.9 Rigify Tutorial #08 - Posing the Rigify rig](https://youtu.be/vKgH5zXIYmM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rig looks like a Rigify rig. Rigify is an add-on that is shipped with Blender. It has a lot of control bones as shown on the 2nd screenshot.

The bones on screenshot 1 are the default appearance of bones in Blender. Could be the meta rig(?).

Anyways, to pose the character you use the control bones.

In a nutshell:

- IK means if you move the hand then the arm will follow but the body will stay put. You move the body and the hands stay put. IK is the default mode. It's the red and yellow controls.
- FK means you rotate the upper arm then the forearm and hand are also moved. It's the green controls. You need to press the *FK->IK ("bone name")* button to have them an effect or use the *IK-FK* slider.
- the circle with the 4 arrows on the ground is the root bone. It moves the whole character
- the yellow cube is the center of gravity or hip controller. Move it down and the character will go down on his knees.
- the feet and hands are controlled by the red squares in IK mode. There is also a smaller red controller for the hand edge.
- the direction of the elbows and knees can be controlled by the poles. You need to enable them in the Rigify settings to see them (*Toggle Pole* button)
- with the big red arrows you can roll and move the upper arms and the thighs, respectively.
- the fingers are controlled with the red "lollipops" (squares). You need to *scale*(!) them to bend/extend the finger.
- there are little spheres. These are tweak bones to finetune the bending/deformation of the knees, elbows, hips, etc.
- the Rigify Properties are in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel
- there are also buttons to hide and reveal the bone layers. A layer is like a collection in the outliner that organizes the bones for the face, hands, feet, etc.
- [image: Rigify properties]