# Some parts of my Rig dont seem to affect my mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, bones

[image: Moved the Hand, but the green parts dont move!][image: Generated Rig from armature]
I just finished generating the rig and now doesnt seem to parent correctly to my mesh. Some parts work just fine but the green part doesnt affect it at all. Does anyone know how I can fix that?

Comment: That's normal and totally fine. It's FK controls and you moved the IK control of the hand. There is a switch in Rigify and a Snap ability. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230112/107598

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a rig that has an IK/FK switch and your pose seems to have it set to use IK.  The bones that aren't moving are the FK (Forward Kinematic) bones.  If the rig is made by rigify or something similar there will be a custom property that controls the switch.  Some rigs will also have a "snap" action to allow you to move the FK bones to match the IK bones.  Here's what this looks like in the rigify UI, but other rigs will have different ways of doing it.

[image: rigify UI showing IK-FK switch]

In this example I have the left hand of the model selected (not shown) so the IK-FK (hand.L) switch shows at the top.  0 means it's in IK mode.  Moving it to one will put it in FK mode.  The two buttons with magnets will cause one set of bones to move to the position of the other.

Again, this is how it works in Rigify and other rigs will have different UIs.