# Rigify Rig Hands & Feet Locked In Place Error

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I'm brand new to rigging models and Blender, I started trying to use Rigify on my model and ran into some issues. I then tried using a more basic model (the one in the file/images). The rigging seems to work fine however the hands and feet are locked into place (they can be rotated individually though). The arms and legs on the actual rig (not the armature or model) seem to move separately to the model when I twist the body too. If anybody's able to take a look and figure out what I've done wrong it'd be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Keep in mind, I am a total beginner so I might need a bit of a walk through.

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUMVWt8HHNPigB1VKQT03clBSiYYabz4/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At a quick glance it seems to be working as it should. In Pose mode, hit the 'N' key with the cursor over the 3D view and then the 'Item' tab down the R/H side of the 3D window. That should bring up all the Rigify settings. You should read up on IK-FK switches which change the influence of the Rigify foot and hand controls as that's really not something that can be explained quickly on this Q&A forum.

Answer (score 0):

The Rigify animation rig has both IK and FK controls. The red squares at the hands and the feet, and the red arrows at the arms and legs are the IK controls. If you want to have them move with the body you can switch their parents from *Root (=1)* to *Torso (=2)*. Either choose an entry from the drop-down menu or enter the number:

[image: IK parent switch]

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230112/107598) is a short description of the controls. I recommend to read the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_features.html) (yeah, it's very brief) and watch a few tutorials about Rigify, IK (Inverse Kinematics) and FK (Forward Kinematics).

The IK & FK controls are on different layers and you can show & hide them with the buttons in the side panel. Whichever of these controls is active will control the character model. There is also a switch in the side panel for this (IK-FK .. (0/1) and FK->IK ... (button)).

**IK parent switch**

Unlike the FK controls, the IK control bones are not a child of the limb that they control. By default, they are a child of the root bone. If they would have no parent at all, they would not move with the armature and would always stay where you have moved them in 3D space.

The Rigify animation rig has a switch for each hand and foot to switch the parent of the IK control dynamically. You need to select the control bone or the red gear bone at the shoulder/pelvis to see the options.

**What is this good for?**

Let's say you want to make your stick-man climb over a wall. He stands in front of the wall to reach the top. But he is a little bit too short.

[image: example animation 1]

He stretches out both arms, puts his left hand on the wall while his right hand is in the air and tries to reach the top of the wall. To make this work, he stands on his tiptoes.

Now what happens to the hands and arms?

The left hand on the wall stays in place and the arm bends while the body is pushed upwards. The other hand (the right), on contrast, moves upwards.

I think you could use here the IK control for the left hand and FK control for the right hand to get the same effect. But let's use IK controls for both to see the difference of the parent settings. The IK control of the left hand has the root bone as parent, while it's switched to the torso for the right hand IK control. This way it moves with the body.

At some point you need to switch the settings else the following will happen. The parent for the left hand IK control is switched, but for the right hand IK control it is still the torso. Instead of staying in place when the hand grabs the wall, it moves around.

[image: animation example 2]

You can create key frames for the parent value and switch them this way. There is also this little button right next to the number that converts a pose depending on the IK parent.

One last thing: for better deformation make sure the model has enough geometry (knees, elbows and butt) and the *Armature* modifier is *on top* of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I also found a really helpful video that explains the whole IK and FK controls situation very well for anybody else confused: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKgH5zXIYmM